# MinGW uses Visual Studio headers instead of its own ones

Tags: cmake, mingw, mingw32, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile libpng with MinGW-w64 (x86_64). I have set up the libpng with CMake using `MinGW Makefiles` generator. When running the make, I get the following output:

```
Scanning dependencies of target png16
[  2%] Building C object CMakeFiles/png16.dir/png.obj
In file included from C:/PROGRA~2/MICROS~3.0/VC/include/vcruntime.h:46:0,
                 from C:/PROGRA~2/MICROS~3.0/VC/include/crtdefs.h:9,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.2-P/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdlib.h:9,
                 from C:\CPP\deps\lpng1617\pngpriv.h:42,
                 from C:\CPP\deps\lpng1617\png.c:14:
C:/PROGRA~2/MICROS~3.0/VC/include/vadefs.h:28:35: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'uintptr_t'
         typedef unsigned __int64  uintptr_t;
                                   ^
In file included from C:/PROGRA~2/MICROS~3.0/VC/include/crtdefs.h:9:0,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.2-P/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/stdlib.h:9,
                 from C:\CPP\deps\lpng1617\pngpriv.h:42,
                 from C:\CPP\deps\lpng1617\png.c:14:
C:/PROGRA~2/MICROS~3.0/VC/include/vcruntime.h:81:1: error: unknown type name 'pack'
 _CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER
 ^
... and more ...
```

Why is MinGW trying to include header files from Visual Studio? The `stdlib.h` at line 9 is including `crtdefs.h` which is being included from Visual Studio and not from MinGW directory. Why?

The `crtdefs.h` does exist in the MinGW directory (next to the `stdlib.h`)

My `%PATH%` variable does not contain any Visual Studio (nor Windows SDK) folders.

After more investigation, I found that `build\CMakeFiles\png16_static.dir\includes_C.rsp` contains `-IC:/PROGRA~2/MICROS~3.0/VC/include`

Comment: Your environment seems broken. Are you running cmake from a Visual Studio command prompt? What are the software versions involved?

Comment: @rubenvb Forgot to mention that, I am using cmake-gui 3.5.2; MinGW-w64 x86_64-4.9.2-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev1; and libpng v16 (1617); I am currently trying to somehow reset all my environment variables to defaults.

Answer (score 0):

After several system restarts, reinstalling MinGW and CMake, and setting the environment variables to defaults, it seems to be working now. Not sure what exactly went wrong.